# How to group this dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this problem:

```
import pandas as pd

stripline = "----------------------------"

rawData = {
    'order number': ['11xa', '11xa', '11xa', '21xb', '31xc'],
    'working area': ['LLA', 'LLE', 'LLS', 'MLA', 'MLE'],
    'time': ['1', '6', '13', '35', '24']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(rawData)
print("original data:")
print(df.head())

print(stripline)

rawData2 = {
    'order number': ['11xa', '21xb', '31xc'],
    'working area': ['LLS', 'MLA', 'MLE'],
    'time': ['20', '35', '24']
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rawData2)

print("expected result:")
print("group after order number, sum all times to that order and choose working field with the biggest time")
print(df2.head())
```

How can I manipulate my dataframe df to get the df2?

I want to sum up all values in the time column that correspond to an order number. I want to use the working field with the highest time and especially I want to keep the rest of the data. The new data frame has three orders, the old one five.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code should do it for you :

```
df.groupby(["order number", "working area"])['time'].agg(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Convert time column to integer:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].astype(int)
```

2) Find `working area` with maximum `time`:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[index, 'max working area'] = df[df['time'] == df[df['order number'] == row['order number']]['time'].max()]['working area'].values[0]
```

3) Aggregate time column:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['order number', 'max working area']).sum()
```

Is this what you wanted?